# Where can I get cheap 28mm D&D figures

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, miniatures, d20-system

There is this one thing called Hero Forge, and it looks really cool, https://www.heroforge.com/ but... it really expensive for what I'm looking for, I also tried Warhammer but that was expensive and the minis were not what I was looking for, I also tried just the plain D&D characters, they were cheap but not what I was looking for, so I was wondering if anyone new a good cheap place I can find my minis... (I am supplying for mor than myself) (about 5 people).

Comment: We’ve closed this question as a duplicate, because we think the existing question should answer your question and we’d rather keep all answers to the question in one place. If for some reason those answers *don’t* answer your question, and your question is different from the linked one, feel free to edit this question, explaining why that question isn’t answering yours, and we can reopen this.